# WSO2 Workflow deployment failing

Tags: wso2

I have a very interesting challenge for the WSO2 BPS experts. We are trying to develop a capability wherein we convert a high level model into WSO2's workflow at the click of a button. The reqd files (.bpel, `.wsdl`, any external files, `deploy.xml`) seem to be getting generated fine. The problem however is when I try to upload the zipped file its throwing an exception

**Cannot find WSDL definition for invoke service {`http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/}DummyServiceInterface`. Required resources not found in the BPEL package ExtractSocialNetworkProcess-2.**

I've spent  2 days trying to figure this out (reviewed namespaces, partner links, imports etc) and locate the problem that's preventing the zip file from getting deployed. I also tried recreating the exact same workflow in WSO2 Studio and much to my surprise the WSO2 studio generated zip file seems to be deploying fine. Now the big question is  "WHAT AM I MISSING WHEN WE ARE GENERATING THE FILES..." If you compare the 2 sets of files, they are very much identical but its so bizaree that one deploys and the other one doesn't. Since I can't attach the zip files, I'll list the contents of individual files below for your reference ...**ExtractSocialNetworkProcess.bpel [Generated from our tool]**

```
<process xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
     xmlns:client="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" 
     xmlns:ns1="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" 
     xmlns:sxed="http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/Editor"
     xmlns:sxt="http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/Trace" 
     xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" 
     suppressJoinFailure="yes"
     targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">

<import namespace="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"   location="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
<import namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" location="DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
<partnerLinks>
   <partnerLink name="client" partnerLinkType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" myRole="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProvider" />
   <partnerLink name="DummyServiceInterface" partnerLinkType="client:DummyServiceInterfacePL" partnerRole="DummyServiceInterfaceRole" />
</partnerLinks>

<variables>
  <variable name="inputVariable" messageType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage" />
  <variable name="outputVariable" messageType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage" />
  <variable name="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_InputVariable" messageType="ns1:extractSocialNetwork" />
  <variable name="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_OutputVariable" messageType="ns1:extractSocialNetworkResponse" />
</variables>

<sequence name="main">
<receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="client" portType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" operation="process" variable="inputVariable" createInstance="yes" />
<scope name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
  <sequence>
     <assign name="Mapping_InvokeESNService_Inputs">
      <copy>
        <from>$inputVariable.payload/client:input</from>
      <to variable="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_InputVariable" part="arg0" />
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <invoke name="InvokeESNService" partnerLink="DummyServiceInterface" portType="ns1:DummyServiceInterface" operation="extractSocialNetwork" inputVariable="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_InputVariable" outputVariable="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_OutputVariable" />
    <assign name="AssignOutputParams">
        <copy>
            <from>
                <literal>
                    <client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessResponse xmlns:client="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <client:output>testing</client:output>
                    </client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessResponse>
                </literal>
            </from>
            <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"></to>
      </copy>         
      <copy>
        <from variable="InvokeESNService_extractSocialNetwork_OutputVariable" part="return" />
        <to>$outputVariable.payload/client:output</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
  </sequence>
</scope>
<reply name="replyOutput" partnerLink="client" portType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" operation="process" variable="outputVariable" />
</sequence>
</process>
```

**`ExtractSocialNetworkProcess.wsdl` [Generated from our tool]**

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
         xmlns:bpws="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/varprop"
      xmlns:client="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
         xmlns:ns1="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" 
         xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" 
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
     xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" 
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" 
         targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">

<plnk:partnerLinkType name="DummyServiceInterfacePL">
  <plnk:role name="DummyServiceInterfaceRole" portType="ns1:DummyServiceInterface" />
</plnk:partnerLinkType>

<import location="DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/"/>
<import location="DummyServiceInterface.wsdl" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/"/>


<types>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
      
  <element name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessRequest">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="input" type="string" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <element name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessResponse">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="output" type="string" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>     
  
  </schema>
</types>

<message name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage">
  <part name="payload" element="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessRequest" />
</message>
<message name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage">
  <part name="payload" element="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProcessResponse" />
</message>

<portType name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
  <operation name="process">
    <input message="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage" />
    <output message="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage" />
  </operation>
</portType>
<plnk:partnerLinkType name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
  <plnk:role name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProvider" portType="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" />
 </plnk:partnerLinkType>
 
 <binding name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessBinding" type="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
   <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
   <operation name="process">
     <soap:operation soapAction="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" />
      <input >
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </input>
  <output >
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
  
  <service name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessService">
         <port name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessPort" binding="client:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:9763/services/ExtractSocialNetworkProcessService" />
  </port>
 </service>
 </definitions>
```

**`deploy.xml` [Autogenerated from our tool]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deploy xmlns="http://www.apache.org/ode/schemas/dd/2007/03" xmlns:ns1="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/samples/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
  <process name="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
    <active>true</active>
    <retired>false</retired>
    <process-events generate="all"/>
    <provide partnerLink="client">
      <service name="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessService" port="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessPort" />
    </provide>
    <invoke partnerLink="DummyServiceInterface">
      <service name="ns1:DummyServiceInterface" port="DummyServiceImplPort" />
    </invoke>
  </process>
</deploy>
```

**`DummyServiceInterface.wsdl` [Third party WSDL used in the workflow ]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://dummyserviceimpl.services.example.com/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://dummyserviceimpl.services.example.com/" name="DummyServiceInterface">
  <import namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" location="DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl" />
  <binding xmlns:ns1="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" name="DummyServiceImplPortBinding" type="ns1:DummyServiceInterface">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
    <operation name="extractSocialNetwork">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="extractTopics">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="extractEvents">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="extractSentiment">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="translateOntologies">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="translateSchemas">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="saveToDB">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" />
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" />
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="DummyServiceInterface">
    <port name="DummyServiceImplPort" binding="tns:DummyServiceImplPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://dev-irpg-stds:8080/dummyServiceImpl/DummyServiceInterface" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

**`DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl` [Since the third party service was created using dotNET and metro stack, its divided into 2 parts ( Binding + Service in one and Msgs and Porttype in the other]**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><definitions xmlns:tns="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/">
<types/>
<message name="extractSocialNetwork">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractSocialNetworkResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractTopics">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractTopicsResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractEvents">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractEventsResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractSentiment">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="extractSentimentResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="translateOntologies">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="translateOntologiesResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="translateSchemas">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg2" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg3" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="translateSchemasResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="saveToDB">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="saveToDBResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="DummyServiceInterface">
<operation name="extractSocialNetwork">
<input xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns1:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractSocialNetworkRequest" message="tns:extractSocialNetwork"/>
<output xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns2:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractSocialNetworkResponse" message="tns:extractSocialNetworkResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="extractTopics" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns3:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractTopicsRequest" message="tns:extractTopics"/>
<output xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns4:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractTopicsResponse" message="tns:extractTopicsResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="extractEvents" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns5:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractEventsRequest" message="tns:extractEvents"/>
<output xmlns:ns6="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns6:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractEventsResponse" message="tns:extractEventsResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="extractSentiment" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input xmlns:ns7="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns7:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractSentimentRequest" message="tns:extractSentiment"/>
<output xmlns:ns8="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns8:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/extractSentimentResponse" message="tns:extractSentimentResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="translateOntologies" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input xmlns:ns9="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns9:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/translateOntologiesRequest" message="tns:translateOntologies"/>
<output xmlns:ns10="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns10:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/translateOntologiesResponse" message="tns:translateOntologiesResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="translateSchemas" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3">
<input xmlns:ns11="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns11:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/translateSchemasRequest" message="tns:translateSchemas"/>
<output xmlns:ns12="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns12:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/translateSchemasResponse" message="tns:translateSchemasResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="saveToDB" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input xmlns:ns13="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns13:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/saveToDBRequest" message="tns:saveToDB"/>
<output xmlns:ns14="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" ns14:Action="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/DummyServiceInterface/saveToDBResponse" message="tns:saveToDBResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
</definitions>
```

**ExtractSocialNetworkProcess.bpel [Generated by WSO2 studio]**

```
<!-- ExtractSocialNetworkProcess BPEL Process [Generated by the Eclipse BPEL Designer] -->
<!-- Date: Mon Mar 05 12:13:11 IST 2012 -->
<bpel:process name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
         targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
         suppressJoinFailure="yes"
         xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample"
         xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:ns="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Import the client WSDL -->
    <bpel:import namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" location="DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
    <bpel:import location="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessArtifacts.wsdl" namespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" 
            importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
         
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- PARTNERLINKS                                                      -->
    <!-- List of services participating in this BPEL process               -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:partnerLinks>
        <!-- The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. -->
        <bpel:partnerLink name="client"
                     partnerLinkType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
                     myRole="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProvider"
                     />
        <bpel:partnerLink name="DummyServiceInterfacePL" partnerLinkType="tns:DummyServiceInterfacePLType" partnerRole="DummyServiceInterfaceRole"></bpel:partnerLink>
    </bpel:partnerLinks>
  
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- VARIABLES                                                         -->
    <!-- List of messages and XML documents used within this BPEL process  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:variables>
        <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
        <bpel:variable name="input" messageType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage"/>
                  
        <!-- 
          Reference to the message that will be returned to the requester
          -->
        <bpel:variable name="output" messageType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage"/>
        <bpel:variable name="DummyServiceInterfacePLResponse" messageType="ns:extractSocialNetworkResponse"></bpel:variable>
        <bpel:variable name="DummyServiceInterfacePLRequest" messageType="ns:extractSocialNetwork"></bpel:variable>
        <bpel:variable name="temp" type="ns1:string"></bpel:variable>
    </bpel:variables>

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- ORCHESTRATION LOGIC                                               -->
    <!-- Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the    -->
    <!-- services integrated within this business process                  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:sequence name="main">
        
        <!-- Receive input from requester. 
             Note: This maps to operation defined in ExtractSocialNetworkProcess.wsdl 
             -->
        <bpel:receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="client"
                 portType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
                 operation="process" variable="input"
                 createInstance="yes"/>
        
        <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="AssignInputParams">
            
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from part="payload" variable="input">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:input]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="arg0" variable="DummyServiceInterfacePLRequest"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            
            
            
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:invoke name="InvokeESNService" partnerLink="DummyServiceInterfacePL" operation="extractSocialNetwork" portType="ns:DummyServiceInterface" inputVariable="DummyServiceInterfacePLRequest" outputVariable="DummyServiceInterfacePLResponse"></bpel:invoke>
        
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="AssignOutputParams">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    <bpel:literal>
                        <tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponse xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><tns:result>tns:result</tns:result>

                        </tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponse>
                    </bpel:literal>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="output" part="payload"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from part="return" variable="DummyServiceInterfacePLResponse"></bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="payload" variable="output">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:result]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:reply name="replyOutput" 
               partnerLink="client"
               portType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
               operation="process" 
               variable="output"
               />
    </bpel:sequence>
</bpel:process>
```

**`ExtractSocialNetworkProcessArtifacts.wsdl` [Generated by WSO2 studio]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" 
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:tns="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" 
             xmlns:vprop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/varprop" 
             xmlns:wsdl="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/" 
             name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"
             targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     TYPE DEFINITION - List of types participating in this BPEL process 
     The BPEL Designer will generate default request and response types
     but you can define or import any XML Schema type and use them as part 
     of the message types.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="DummyServiceInterfacePLType">
      <plnk:role name="DummyServiceInterfaceRole" portType="wsdl:DummyServiceInterface"/>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
    <import location="DummyServiceInterfaceSchema.wsdl" namespace="http://dummyserviceinterface.services.example.com/"/>
    
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">

            <element name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequest">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="input" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>

            <element name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="result" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     MESSAGE TYPE DEFINITION - Definition of the message types used as 
     part of the port type defintions
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <message name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage">
        <part element="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequest" name="payload"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage">
        <part element="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponse" name="payload"/>
    </message>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PORT TYPE DEFINITION - A port type groups a set of operations into
     a logical service unit.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    

    <!-- portType implemented by the ExtractSocialNetworkProcess BPEL process -->
    <portType name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
        <operation name="process">
            <input message="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessRequestMessage"/>
            <output message="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessResponseMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>   
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PARTNER LINK TYPE DEFINITION
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
        <plnk:role name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessProvider" portType="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"/>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
    

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     BINDING DEFINITION - Defines the message format and protocol details
     for a web service.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <binding name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessBinding" type="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="process">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://wso2.org/bps/sample/process"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     SERVICE DEFINITION - A service groups a set of ports into
     a service unit.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <service name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
        <port binding="tns:ExtractSocialNetworkProcessBinding" name="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ExtractSocialNetworkProcess"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**`deploy.xml` [Generated by WSO2 studio]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deploy xmlns="http://www.apache.org/ode/schemas/dd/2007/03" 
       xmlns:dummyserviceimpl.services.mycompany.com="http://dummyserviceimpl.services.example.com/" 
       xmlns:sample="http://wso2.org/bps/sample">
  <process name="sample:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess">
    <active>true</active>
    <retired>false</retired>
    <process-events generate="all"/>
    <provide partnerLink="client">
      <service name="sample:ExtractSocialNetworkProcess" port="ExtractSocialNetworkProcessPort"/>
    </provide>
    <invoke partnerLink="DummyServiceInterfacePL">
      <service name="dummyserviceimpl.services.example.com:DummyServiceInterface" port="DummyServiceImplPort"/>
    </invoke>
  </process>
</deploy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload your original bpel package and auto generated bpel package to some location and share the link.Then I can check what is causing the problem . Or can you send a mail to developer mailing list at wso2 with relevant bpel packages.

Regards
Nandika